# Is there a way to update views in StackView without removing the view and re adding it?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have views which use autolayout. I know the exact width I want each view to be (each width is different). The StackView is nested inside of a collection view. The views inside the stack view are loaded dynamically from the main view controller. I want to update the stack views views when the collection view reloads without removing the views and adding them again. I cannot remove the views and re add them because some of the views have textfields which will dismiss the keyboard if reloaded. I have explained the code below

Thank you for any help.

---

## EDIT

This is the layout I am looking for.

[image: example]

I use [Carbon](https://github.com/ra1028/Carbon) for rendering the views into the collection view:

```swift
    private func render() {
        renderer.render {
            Section(
                id: "testing row collection",
                cells: {
                    Row(id: "row id", data: [
                        Input(
                            id: 6,
                            props: InputContent.State(
                                text: self.state.inputText,
                                placeholder: "Search",
                                size: .medium
                            ),
                            onChange: { [weak self] text in
                                print("text is:", text)
                                self?.state.inputText = text
                            }
                        )
                    ])
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

NOTE: the image and code do not match implementation. The image shows 3 views, the code only shows 1.

The class `Row` is the class that renders the view that holds the UIStackView. Inside that I have a list of views, at the moment only 1 view. It's sets `text` to be `self.state.inputText` which is a variable in the view controller. Then on any change in the textfield I set `self.state.inputText` to be that text. When the variable `state` is set, `render()` is run.

The `Row` class:

This class renders the actual UIView which is called `RowContent`. It calls the `updateState(state:)` method shown in the `RowContent` class. This is called when the collection view renders

The `RowContent` class:

```swift
class RowContent: UIView {

    var stack: UIStackView

    var state: State
    
    struct State {
        var views: [UIView] = [UIView]()
    }
    
    public func updateState(_ state: State? = nil) {
        self.state = state ?? self.state
        //updateView()
    }
    
    required init(state: State) {
        self.state = state
        self.stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: state.views)
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.setupStackView()
    }

    ...

}
```

The stack view gets populated in the initialiser with the views, then I add the constraints in `setupStackview()`

At the moment, the views never update when the collection view re renders, meaning that the text property in Input never gets updated. I want to update the views when the collection view re renders. This would be in the `updateView()` method which is commented out. I do not know how to update the views in the collectionView without removing the views and re adding them.

Thanks.

I have added an example here: https://github.com/4ndrewHarri5/ExampleRow

Comment: A little confusing... regardless of your sizing issue, do you ***need*** to use a collection view? Or would a stack view (once you understand how to update an arranged subview's height without dismissing the keyboard) suffice?

Comment: Hi, I don't need to use a collection view, A stack view would be preferred. Thanks

Comment: OK - is your goal then to have a horizontally-scrolling stackView? It would help if you show an image of the layout you're trying to achieve...

Comment: Hi @DonMag, I have updated the question thanks

Comment: Is your image showing 3 "columns"? Where, it appears, the 1st and 3rd columns are equal size and the middle column is wider? And, what is editable that brings up the keyboard? The Search "cell"? The middle cell? Do the 1st and 2nd columns show the same text, or might it be different? And, will this eventually have a series of "rows" that look like this?

Comment: @DonMag The image is different from the code shown. The code only shows the last view in the image. The view widths are calculated in layoutSubviews and set as constraints in there. I already have the logic for the widths, it is updating the views when an update occurs which I am struggling with.

Comment: @DonMag the search cell in the image is editable. In the code it is the `Input` class. The first and second views do have the same text in the image.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm having difficulty grasping your ultimate goal. Is this what you're going for? https://imgur.com/a/5A9I78q

Comment: @DonMag Yes exactly that. But with the implementation I have, when I type, the keyboard gets dismissed if I update the views in the stack view when the collection view updates

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try...

We start with a Tag "base" view class - it will set the background color and rounded corners for the Tag views:

```
// background and rounded corners
class TagBaseView: UIView {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        layer.cornerRadius = 12
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.96, green: 0.95, blue: 0.97, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    
}
```

Subclass `TagBaseView`, adding a `UILabel`:

```
class TagLabelView: TagBaseView {
    
    let label = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    override func commonInit() -> Void {
        super.commonInit()

        label.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
        ])

    }
    
}
```

Subclass `TagBaseView`, adding a `UITextField`:

```
class TagFieldView: TagBaseView {
    
    let field = UITextField()
    
    var textChangeCallback: ((String)->())?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    override func commonInit() -> Void {
        super.commonInit()
        
        field.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
        addSubview(field)
        field.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // constrain text field Leading / Trailing
            field.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            field.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            // center it vertically
            field.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            // require at least 8-pts Top and Bottom
            field.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            field.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
        ])
        
        field.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        
    }

    @objc func textDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) -> Void {
        guard let s = textField.text else {
            return
        }
        // tell the controller the text changed
        textChangeCallback?(s)
    }
    
}
```

View controller class - creates a horizontal stack view, with a `TagLabelView` "left" view, a `TagLabelView` "center" view, and a `TagFieldView` "right" view.

When we edit the text field in the "right" view, it will use a closure to "call back" to the controller where we handle the text change and update the left and center views:

```
class EditStackViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let stack: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.spacing = 8
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
    
    let leftView = TagLabelView()
    let centerView = TagLabelView()
    let rightView = TagFieldView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(stack)
        
        stack.addArrangedSubview(leftView)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(centerView)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(rightView)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain stack view Top / Leading / Trailing
            //  (no Bottom or Height)
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
            // make "center" view 45% of the width
            centerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.45),
            
            // make "right" view equal width to "left" view
            rightView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftView.widthAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        rightView.field.placeholder = "Search"

        // TagSearchView tells us when the field is being edited
        rightView.textChangeCallback = { [weak self] str in
            guard let self = self else {
                return
            }
            self.leftView.label.text = str
            self.centerView.label.text = str
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the indepth answer. I don't think you understood me quite enough. The stack view is nested inside of a collectionView cell. The leftView, centerView and rightView are passed into that cell from the viewController in an array. On a reload I want to update the views. Each view is different so I do not know the type to be-able to set text of the view or set any other property when the text changes. The cell with the stack view is suppose to be generic enough that any UIViews can be passed in and the view gets updated without having to set the properties on text change. Thanks

Comment: @AndrewHarris - as I said in my comments, having trouble grasping your goal. I asked if you *needed* a collection view, and you said no, a stack view would work. The image you added to your question doesn't show anything really related to a collection view. If you can provide complete detail about what you're going for - i.e. not just 3 rounded rectangles - I can try to help. And, try to do so without needing whatever you're doing with "Carbon" ... I think that's just confusing things.

Comment: I meant as in using a nested collectionView instead of a nested stackView. As in replicating a stackview by using a collectionview instead, as I was having trouble updating the views inside of the stackview. I mentioned carbon because you declare the views you want in a declarative way, so it says "I want a section with cells, the cell I want is Row" then inside of row I pass in the "data" which are the views inside of the stack view. I am sorry for confusing you, I didn't want to provide too much detail that might not be relevant. I can provide an example project showing the issue.

Comment: I have added an example in the question. Thanks

Comment: @AndrewHarris - I grabbed your GitHub repo... tapping in either "field" on the second row brings up the keyboard, and typing in that field updates the "first" row, including changing the height when it needs to wrap. So... still not clear what the issue is?

Comment: If you go into `Row` and uncomment the line 36 the keyboard dismisses each time, this is because the views get removed and added again. I am not sure how to update the views inside of the stackview without doing this. Thanks

Comment: The views need to be refreshed as If you look at the inputs text, it should be set to `inputText` so when you type in any of the inputs, the text should be the same across all of the textfields

Comment: @AndrewHarris - Are you trying to create a new "tag" with every character entered? When I un-comment that line and launch your example, I see this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gPIw.png ... I tap the left placeholder and I see this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEaPc.png ... when I type the letter A I see this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvCXx.png ??? What is *supposed* to happen?

Comment: did your keyboard get dismissed? This is because the method `updateView` removes all the stackviews subviews and re adds them. Basically all of the views in the stackview should be updated when the collection view reloads. I have updated the repo to add a tag to the Row. With `updateView` commented, this tags text does not get updated which shows that none of the views in the Row get updated. If you uncomment `updateView` the tag in Row does get updated, but the textfield keyboard gets dismissed and the textField no longer works. I want to keep on typing and update all the views

Comment: @AndrewHarris - for me to help, you need to explain what you are *trying* to do, not "here's what I'm doing and it's not working." Right now, I see a label and two text fields. I have no idea what's supposed to be a collection view, I have no idea why there are two text fields, I have no idea why you're removing views and creating new views (and reloading a collection view) each time a character is entered.

Comment: I am trying to allow any amount of views to be placed into a collectionView cell's UIStackView and have the views be updated when the collection view reloads. The examples show example views being placed into the stackview, but it doesn't have to be those views, it could be any view and any amount of views. I also am using a textField in one of the views to show that the stackview views don't update on a reloading the collectionViews data. I don't know how to explain it any better

Comment: @AndrewHarris - if you have a text field in a collectionView cell, you won't be able to keep it as first responder (keep the keyboard visible) if you reload the collection view. But, you don't need to reload a whole collectionView to update a single (or set) of cells. And, you don't need to delete and re-create views from a stack view just to update their properties. You may need to take a step back and re-think your approach. Maybe start without the Pods that may be doing things you aren't aware of, or have no control over.

Comment: @AndrewHarris - this has turned into too much of a discussion for Stack Overflow comments, so one last thing: Maybe try re-doing your GitHub example with some "logical" data. Right now, you have two text fields in a cell, and you've written code that reloads the entire collection view with each character entered. Surely, that is not your *intent*. So, rather than thinking "how do I keep the keyboard visible" you need to think "why am I reloading the entire collection view".